# What is for the parameter of axis(None) of zscore in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, axis

stats.zscore(a, axis=0, ddof=0) in this code,
Can you explain the parameter of axis?

It is not different from NumPy axis.

axis : int or "None", optional
If axis is equal to None, the array is first raveled. If axis is an integer, this is the axis over which to operate. Default is 0.

Here's link 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.zscore.html

Comment: It's not different from numpy axis. Scipy operates on numpy arrays. If you pass None, the array on which you are trying to calculate the z-score will be raveled (converted to a 1-dimensional array). Otherwise, it will calculate it on the first axis (axis=0).